# gmail api suddenly returns 403 forbidden

Tags: vb.net, gmail-api

I have a VB.net application that has been working great with the gmail.api "gmail.send" scope for months.  I have about 3 dozen different gmail accounts that have successfully integrated using OAUTH2.  Starting yesterday one of the accounts began returning a 403 Forbidden error.  Today another one started doing the same thing.  Meanwhile, the others are all working just fine, sending plenty of messages successfully every day.  My app hasn't been verified yet, but I would think if it were to be shut down then all of the accounts would not work.  Likewise if there was some sort of throttling I would think it would apply to my app as a whole and not affect individual users.  It seems very strange that some work and others don't.  Any ideas?

Comment: So you error happens sometime but not the others? Why do you mean your app hasn't been verified yet? Maybe some more information about the errors you are receiving would be great. Refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to try to improve your question. 
Can you ask to your users if they removed access for your application?

Comment: @Raserhin the users have not removed access for my application.  By not verified, I mean that my app hasn't gone through Google's review process yet.  That doesn't seem to prevent it from working, though.  I realize this question is vague, but I was mainly wondering if anyone has experienced problems in the last few days with the messages.send scope.  I'm sure this problem is affecting other people.  My app has been working flawlessly for months and now I get the 403 error when using messages.send.

Comment: I should say about 3 of the 24 email accounts that have gone through the OAUTH2 process to integrate gmail with my application are having the problem.  The rest work just fine when using the messages.send endpoints.  And they all worked fine until last week when this problem cropped up.

Answer (score 1):

I dove into the API instructions. I had been appending a ?key=[gmail application client id] parameter to the POST googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send url. I'm not sure why I did that originally, but as of a few days ago it began causing a 403 forbidden error for some of the linked gmail accounts. Problem solved!